# C++ classes that need to refer to each other both in generic and subclass code

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have three classes, `config`, `circuit`, and `conn`, that hold pointers to each other, like so:

```
struct config { /* ... */ };
struct circuit {
    config *cfg;
    /* ... */
};
struct conn {
    config *cfg;
    circuit *ckt;
    /* ... */
}
```

(There is no access control and no pointer intelligence because this program is about halfway through being converted from C to C++.  That's not important right now.)

When these classes are subclassed, all three of them are *always* subclassed in a group:

```
struct foo_config  : config  { /* ... */ };
struct foo_circuit : circuit { /* ... */ };
struct foo_conn    : conn    { /* ... */ };
```

Furthermore, it is a runtime invariant that the `cfg` pointer in a `foo_circuit` or `foo_conn` will *always* point to an instance of a `foo_config`, and the `ckt` pointer in a `foo_conn` will *always* point to an instance of a `foo_circuit`.  This is currently being enforced with `dynamic_cast` and assertions.  There are currently two different `foo`s, but there may be more in the future.

Is it possible to arrange matters so that the `cfg` and `ckt` pointers remain accessible to methods of the generic `circuit` and `conn` classes, and have the generic type there, but in methods of the subclasses, those pointers have the appropriate subclass type, and the above invariant becomes compile-time enforced?  If so, how?  If not, what would you suggest I do instead?

I prefer answers that minimize the amount of boilerplate I have to write for each set of subclasses. I also prefer answers that still work if the subclasses are defined in an anonymous namespace and not visible in any header.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace all direct access to the data members with getters and setters, then you can define type specific getters and setters for each subclass, and with those the compiler can enforce types. Below is an example, note that I have defined a template class to simplify the creation of subclasses.

```
struct config { /* ... */ };

struct circuit {
private: 
    config *cfg;
protected:
    void set_cfg(config* _cfg) { cfg = _cfg; }
    config* get_cfg() { return cfg; }
};

template <typename CFG>
struct my_circuit : circuit {
public:
    // type specific setters/getters
    void set_cfg(CFG* _cfg) { circuit::set_cfg(_cfg); }
    CFG* get_cfg() { return dynamic_cast<CFG*>(circuit::get_cfg()); }
};

// below is how you define two different sets of subclasses:
struct foo_config  : config  { /* ... */ };
typedef my_circuit<foo_config> foo_circuit;

struct bar_config  : config  { /* ... */ };
typedef my_circuit<bar_config> bar_circuit;

// example usage
foo_config foo_cfg;
foo_circuit foo_ckt;
bar_config bar_cfg;

foo_ckt.set_cfg(&foo_cfg); // okay
foo_ckt.set_cfg(&bar_cfg); // not okay, compiler error!
```

Inside the base classes you don't have to change anything. Inside the subclasses you have to replace direct access to these member variables with the corresponding getters, so that you get the proper type conversion. Note that I converted the data member in the base class to private, to get the compiler's help in detecting all the direct references to these data members in subclasses.